How to make a bootstrap col sticky whose height is bigger than screen height?
I have a bootstrap container with a row and 2 columns (9, 3). I want to make the second column float on right like an element would with position sticky. But the problem is the height of the second column (col-lg-3) is dynamic and can get longer than the screen height. In that case, sticky-top does work, but then the full height (end contents) of column can't be seen until I scroll to the very bottom.
Here is a shortened snippet of html.
<div class="container-fluid mt-3 main">
    <div class="row gx-3">
        <div class="col-lg-9 order-1 order-lg-0">
            ... long content here ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 order-0 order-lg-1">
            <div class="card card-content about mb-3 order-0 sticky-top">
                <div class="card-body px-3 pt-3 text-center">
                    .. content here .. dynamic height, can go more than vh
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

To give a clearer idea, I'm trying to do how the Intro section on facebook profile is like, it scrolls up and down when you scroll but sticks to the bottom when the content ends, instead of having to reach the bottom of the screen to see the whole content.

If any custom css / jquery is needed, that would work too, and I haven't done anything to the existing divs positioning or overflow manually.

note that .containe-fluid should be .container-fluid.
